# Spyder IDE - Cancel opening large variables without restarting the entire program

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am working with large Pandas dataframes in Spyder. Occasionally I accidentally click the large dataframes in the Variable Explorer window and Spyder will very hang for very long periods while it tries to open.

The only way I have found to stop this process is to close Spyder completely and then reopen.

Is it possible to:

1. Cancel the request to view the variable without closing the program?
2. Set a default so Spyder will only display the first 1000 rows of very large objects such as dataframes?

Answer (score 4):

(*Spyder developer here*) My answers:

> Cancel the request to view the variable without closing the program?

No, that's not possible, sorry.

> Set a default so Spyder will only display the first 1000 rows of very large objects such as dataframes?

That's already in place. The problem is the size in memory of your dataframes because Spyder needs to make a copy of them to graphically display them.

To fix this problem, we are planning to use more efficient serialization libraries (e.g. `pyarrow`) in Spyder 5, to be released in 2021.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sounds good that you're addressing this in future releases, however, in the meantime, how difficult would it be to incorporate a warning if the user tries to open a very large dataset i.e. a pandas dataframe with 100,000 + rows? And cancelling the request if the user decides? Or rather than displaying the actual dataframe, a copy of the dataframe i.e. the 1000 rows using .head(), is displayed to the user?

Comment: It all depends on your available RAM. I can easily open Dataframes with 1 million rows in my laptop with 8Gb of RAM. Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) to keep discussing this until we find an acceptable solution.

Comment: I have a list of 62 elements - all pandas dfs - and spyder crashes. I use the latest version of spyder, at a i7 Mac with 16 GB RAM. What i should check ? does not seem to me logical this crash